# ¿como obtengo la hora y fecha de ingreso de un usuario al sistema? en grails

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy

quiero mostrar la hora de ingreso al sistema de un usuario, pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo, estoy usando Grails and groovy, y mi gestor de BD es MySQL, quiero registrar y mostrar la hora de ultimo ingreso, espero que me puedan ayudar...

Comment: Agrega qué has intentado o qué llevas hasta el momento, así es mucho más fácil ayudarte

Answer (score 1):

¿Cuál versión de Grails estas usando?
Bueno, esto te puede servir.
Tienes que activar los eventos de springsecurity en /grails-app/conf/application.groovy 
Pon el siguiente código

```
'grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true // enable events



grails.plugin.springsecurity.onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->
    User.withTransaction {
        def user = User.findById(appCtx.springSecurityService.principal.id)
        if(!user.isAttached())
            user.attach()
        user.lastLoginTime = new Date() // update login time
        user.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    }
}
```

Y en tu User domain usa el siguiente código para el ultimo logueo o el actual logueo
`class User
  {
    Date lastLoginDate
    Date currentLoginDate
  }`

Comment: estoy utilizando la versión 3.8 , efectivamente con sprintSecurity, voy a probar con la opción que me diste, te agradezco

Comment: 2019-12-04 08:54:48.924 ERROR --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp
2019-12-04 08:54:48.979 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query

Comment: me genera ese error al reiniciar mi app

Comment: Parece que por defecto no soporta el valor de fecha "0000-00-00" asi que tienes que agregar en las propiedades: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull      Esto para que ese valor lo transforme a NULL

Comment: que tal amigo, estoy continuando con el proyecto, ya agregue a las propiedades la conversión a null. y en mi dominio user los tuve que poner en null porque iniciaba usuarios en BootStrap, me crea los campos en la tabla pero cuando inicio sesión ' No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.withTransaction() is applicable for argument types: (script15790434270821274704038$_run_closure1$_closure3) values: [script15790434270821274704038$_run_closure1$_closure3@5e1c1102] '